# Bundler::GemNotFound Issue after installing Redmine on Debian

Tags: ruby, debian, redmine

I am trying to install Remine on Debian server. Apache is the Http Server and MySql as database. Installation is complete. Its shows an error Could not find nokogiri-1.8.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound). 
I haven't hosted an Ruby application before. 
Tried most of the commands found on internet about this issue. 
[This is the URL](http://redmine.donams.com/) where you can see the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

During the deployment of the app, there should be a step `bundle install`. This step is performed by a gem called `bundler`, that needs to be installed prior to this step. Add `gem install bundler` to install it. It looks at the files `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` and install all the missing dependencies. Like a `package.json` for `npm install`. Remine must have a Gemfile somehwere. You should probably refer to their deployment wiki or contact them otherwise.

You can also check that the Gemfile specifies the right version of Nokogiri. Specify it otherwise.

Nokogiri is also known to fail installing randomly. You can try adding a manual `sudo gem install nokogiri 1.8.4` after `bundle install`, see if that helps.

Comment: Yes. I have done all this. It simple doesn't works. Any other suggestions...?

Comment: Can you check that the Gemfile specifies the right version of Nokogiri? Specify it otherwise. Nokogiri is also known to fail installing randomly. You can try adding a manual `sudo gem install nokogiri 1.8.4` after the `bundle install`, see if that helps.

Comment: yes. I did and it is there. And again I installed using the same command. Not working. Can't figure out this one. I temporary dropped this. Will try to install again after testing on a VM.